# Python3: Change the items on a list with function and while loop. Why is my code not running properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While doing the following task I found my code not running on Jupiter notebooks properly (have restarted the Kernel several times already):

> Function Challenge: create replacement function
>
> Create a function, str_replace, that takes 2 arguments: int_list and
>   index
>
> int_list is a list of single digit integers
>
> index is the index that will be checked - such as with int_list[index]
>
> Function replicates purpose of task "replace items in a list" above
>   and replaces an integer with a string "small" or "large"
>
> return int_list
>
> Test the function!

My goal is to change all the elements of the list [0,1,2,3,4] to ["small","small", "small","small","small"] with the following code:

```
int_list=[0,1,2,3,4]
index=0
def str_replace(int_list,index):
    if index <5:
        int_list[index]="small"
        return int_list
    else:
        int_list[index]="large"
        return int_list

str_replace(int_list,index)
while index <=4:
    index+=index
    str_replace(int_list,index)
```

When I run it, it keeps running and not giving me back any output. However if I run everything but the last while loop I get: ["small",1,2,3,4]. Can anybody help me understanding why this happens?

Comment: Look at the line ` index += index` since index is 0 at the beginning index remains 0 and the while loop continues till infinity :) Change this line to `index+=1` and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in an infinite loop because index is always smaller than 4,

you do `index += index` but because index is 0 nothing adds up and you stay in the loop.

If you change it to `index += 1`instead - that should solve your problem.

Also to not get an `out of range` error change it to `while index < 4:` or alternatively put the `index +=1` at the bottom of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are in an infinite loop : `index` is always <= 4. See : `index` is initialised to 0 and the new assignment `index+=index` will never change the value of index to higher than 0. Did you mean `index += 1` ?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense! 
But now I get this error:
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-c1ac756ce12b> in <module>() 13 while index <=4:

     14     index+=1

---> 15     str_replace(int_list,index)

     16 

     17 


<ipython-input-2-c1ac756ce12b> in str_replace(int_list, index)

      7         return int_list

      8     else:

----> 9         int_list[index]="large"

     10         return int_list

     11 



IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: On the last loop : your index takes the value 5. Change the loop condition to `index < 4`. On the last iteration : index will be 3+1  instead of 4+1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem was with the return statement with every chamge

```
int_list=[0,1,2,3,4]
index=0
def str_replace(int_list,index):
if index <5:
    int_list[index]="small"

else:
    int_list[index]="large"


while index <=4:
str_replace(int_list,index)
index+=1

print(int_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use

```
[ 'small' if index < 5 else 'large' for index in int_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int_list=[0,1,2,3,6]
index=0
def str_replace(int_list,index):
    if int_list[index] < 5:
        int_list[index] = "small"
    else:
        int_list[index] = "large"

while index <=4:
    str_replace(int_list,index)
    index+=1

print(int_list)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.